# symfony6 $this->container->get('app.our.useful.thing')

Tags: service, symfony6

I am sorry, I read the docs, but I don't get symfony6 anymore.

```
services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file

  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

  # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
  # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
  App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
      - '../src/Entity/'
      - '../src/Kernel.php'
      - '../src/EventListener
  app.our.useful.thing:
    class: App\OurUsefulThing
    public: true
```

My src/OurUsefulThing.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class OurUsefulThing
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello Service";
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function someActionName(Request $request)() {
    $value = $this->container->get('app.our.useful.thing')->sayHello();
}
```

Error Message

```
Service "app.our.useful.thing" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\CategoriesController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

It was in symfony4 so easy. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am a relative noob at a lot of this, but I've circled the drain on this several times, so I apologize in advance for my minimal ability to answer with articulate lingo stuffs. Also, it's been a while since this was posted, so mostly answering in case my stumblings can help someone else.
I think we need to pan out and see more of the controller, and not try to hit the container directly. (also hopefully I can extrapolate out and make stuff up that matches what's here) So in controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\OurUsefulThing;
use OtherUseStuffsLikeRequestEtc;

class Controller extends AbstractController
{
    public $ourUsefulThing;

    public function __construct(OurUsefulThing $ourUsefulThing)
        {
            $this->ourUsefulThing = $ourUsefulThing;
        }
    public function someActionName(Request $request) {
        $value = $this->ourUsefulThing->sayHello();
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's at least close enough to help find the next step.